# Converting word file to pdf file fastest way

Tags: python, pdf, ms-word

I am using Python as a backend file handler and i have tried different libraries and com itself to convert word files to pdf such as;

and also pythoncom.CoInitialize().

The fastest one is aspose but it needs a license otherwise it puts a watermark in the pdf file. I was wondering is there anything else that i can use to speed up my process?

ps: i tried using packages that uses libreoffice but it changes the format (design) of the file. it is no use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running windows, you can use comtypes simply. For example,

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client

wdFormatPDF = 17

in_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
out_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[2])

word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

Comment: I have already used comtypes it is not that fast. Thanks.